# Chezmoi: ignore files and subdirectories

Tags: dotfiles

I've been trying to add Neovim configuration:

```
~ $ ls .config/nvim
autoload  custom.vim  init.vim  plugged  yankring_history_v2.txt
```

Working directories `autoload/`, `plugged/`, and file `yankring_history_v2.txt` are not welcome in `~/.local/share/chezmoi` repository, naturally.

I tried to put [.chezmoiignore](https://www.chezmoi.io/reference/special-files-and-directories/chezmoiignore/) into `~/.config/nvim` in the hope that

```
~ $ chezmoi add .conf/nvim
```

will skip copying the working directories into `~/.local/share/chezmoi` repository. This is not the case, unfortunately.

`~/.config/nvim/.chezmoiignore`:

```
autoload/
plugged/
yankring_history*.txt
```

`~ $ chezmoi add .conf/nvim`;

```
~ ᐅ ls .local/share/chezmoi/dot_config/nvim
autoload  custom.vim  dot_chezmoiignore  init.vim  plugged  yankring_history_v2.txt
```

Of course, I can make `.gitignore` in the chezmoi repository, but I don't think that would be the right way to go.

What is the right way in my case? My purpose is clear, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.chezmoiignore` lives in the repository (and controls `$ chezmoi add`):
`~/.local/share/chezmoi/.chezmoiignore`:

```
README.*

# Neovim
**/autoload/
**/autoload/**/*
**/plugged/
**/plugged/**/*
**/yankring_history*.txt
```

[Discussion](https://github.com/twpayne/chezmoi/issues/1237)